# adjust padding/width of parbox to make space for logos?

Tags: tikzposter, logos, parbox

I am using the tikzposter class to create a poster for a conference. For conference posters I've typically included two logos, one on either side of the title box, but in this case the box isn't leaving enough room for the left and right-side logos -- I have to make them tiny to fit, and it looks bad.

There's plenty of padding around the text in the \parbox, but my attempts to add to the \parbox call have only affected the text: the box itself has remained the same size.

Is there a way to alter this? Here's what I currently have with all sensitive stuff replaced:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering{The Text Before the Breaking Colon}: \\Text After the Colon}}
\author{Dewey, Cheatham \& Howe}
\date{\today}
\institute{That Little Mansion on the Hill}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetheme{Rays}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\node[xshift = 4cm] at (TP@title.west) {\includegraphics[width=12cm]{images/blah_header.png}};
\node[xshift = -4cm] at (TP@title.east) {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{images/blah_header_2.png}};
```

Here is what I am talking about: I took two screenshots of the header with dummy text and dummy icons. These don't illustrate the problem as well as I'd like because the "A" and "B" dummy graphics are square, where the logos I intend to use are landscape-shaped rectangles (that is they don't read NEARLY as well as the "A" and "B" here do).

I am wondering if there is a way to change the size of the surrounding \parbox. Changing arguments to \parbox affect the text within it but not the box itself, so

[image: parbox with lots of text]

but if you remove all but a little of the text,

[image: parbox with not much text]

... the box itself takes up just as much space, there's just more whitespace around the text. I want to adjust the padding (I guess you'd call it) surrounding the text in the \parbox to make room on either side of it for the logos/icons. Even in the first graphic there is whitespace I'd like to squeeze out. I want to shrink the boundaries of the box around the text inside.

Maybe I need to use something other than \parbox? I'm sorry if I'm being unclear. I'm trying to do this in Overleaf and I don't have tons of experience with LaTeX.

Comment: it's not clear what you what to do, but `\parbox{\linewidth}` makes the box the full width, `\parbox{.5\linewidth}` would make it half as wide. Unrelated but `\centering{The Text Before the Breaking Colon}` should be `\centering The Text Before the Breaking Colon` The brace group isn't doing anything in that context.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the .5 squeezes/constrains the text but leaves the containing box the same size -- that is, doing this actually increases the whitespace between the text and the borders of the box. What I'm trying to do is get the box to hug the text more closely, so there will be more room for the logos to the left and to the right.

Comment: I am not sure which box you mean the only box explicitly constructed here is the `\parbox` that is the width that you specify `\linewidth` in the posting. If you mean some box in the internal tikzposter title layout, perhaps its size is fixed, but I am not sure how you are measuring it.